# How to achive a custom nested RESTful url in tastypie?

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I'm using django-tastypie , I have a resource for list of musics like this :

```
/api/v1/musics
```

which returns a list of available musics , each music object has an attribute called votes (it's an IntegerField) , I'd like to have an endpoint like :

```
/api/v1/musics/69/vote
```

and users can send POST requests like this :

```
{
'vote':'+1'
}
```

how can I achieve this ?
My django model :

```
class Music(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(_("Music Title"), max_length=255, null=True)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, verbose_name=_("Album"), null=True)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, verbose_name=_("Artist"), null=True)
    genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre, verbose_name=_("Genre"), null=True)
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language, verbose_name=_("Language"), null=True)
    file = models.FilePathField(_("Track File Path"), max_length=1000)
    length = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_("Music length in seconds"), null=True)
    is_playing = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    current_playlist = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    vote = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s [Music Object]" % self.title
```

my resource definition for music :

```
class TrackResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = musics_models.Track.objects.all()
        list_allowed_methods = ['get']
        detail_allowed_methods = ['get']
        resource_name = 'tracks'
        # authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
        filtering = {
            'title': ALL,
            'is_playing': ['exact'],
            'current_playlist': ['exact']
        }

        pass
```

Comment: can you provide some samples.. or minimal configuration would be better and also I'm not sure but `/api/v1/musics/69/vote` will give the expected  result right ?

Comment: @RajaSimon not sure what you mean but I provide more information .
`/api/v1/musics/69/vote` is exactly what I need , but I'm looking for the right way to implement this.